# Relations between secants of complex algebraic plane curves and meromorphic functions of bounded order.

Tags: algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces

At the start of section 2 of [this article](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2023-60-03/S0273-0979-2023-01787-4/home.html), the authors say the following (emphasis mine):

> The work of Bernard Riemann in the 1850s and 1860s changed the direction of the theory of algebraic curves, replacing curves in the complex projective plane with branched coverings of the complex projective line—the Riemann sphere—and *questions about tangents and secants by questions about spaces of meromorphic functions with bounded pole orders.*

The italicised line looks unfamiliar to me.

**What is the relation between tangents and secants of plane curves and meromorphic functions with bounded pole orders?**

I understand Riemann surface theory, covering spaces, basics of algebraic curves and complex analysis.

Comment: This sounds like it's about the Riemann-Roch theorem, which is a statement about the dimension of spaces of meromorphic functions on a compact Riemann surface that have certain constraints on their poles. These constraints are given by so-called "divisors". If a compact Riemann surface is embedded in an ambient space, like $\mathbb{CP}^2$, then planes (complex lines) that lie in this space define "intersection divisors" according to how they intersect the Riemann surface (i.e. is it a tangent or does it intersect transversally).

Comment: Thanks. I understand that. But is there a direct relation between tangent/secant and the meromorphic functions?

Comment: Are you asking what questions Riemann's contemporaries had about tangents and secants? I'm afraid I can't help with that. In the case of a curve in $\mathbb{CP}^2$, any quotient of homogeneous polynomials of the same order defines a meromorphic function on the curve, and similarly any line $ax+by+cz=0$ defines a meromorphic function near its intersections with the curves, which corresponds to the intersection divisor, but I guess you'd already be aware of that.